# Reading through a text file line by line and checking if that line has a certain string

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to read a text file line by line using Shell Scripting. What I have been doing is

```
while read line
do
   var1=$(grep -s "Completed" $line)
   var2=$(grep -s "Script Finished" $line)

if[ "$var1" = "$line" ]
   break
else
   if[ "$var2" = "$line" ]
       count='expr $count + 1'
   else
      countinue
   fi
fi
done < file.txt
```

If you have any suggestions please let me know! I am open to other options because I have been trying to do this way too long.

**TO CLARIFY:**

I am going through a file line by line (while loop) then I am grepping that line to see if "Completed" is a substring and grepping to see if "Script Finished" is a substring (Grep will set the variable to the whole line). So then when I do the checks if the variable is Completed I want to break out of the while loop if not check if "Script Finished" is a substring so I can increment a counter (I am trying to count how many scripts finished before "Complete").

**CONFUSED ABOUT:**

When I do var1=$(grep -s "Completed" $line) why does it find all instances of Completed... I thought if im going through line by line it will only find the instances in that certain line.

**EDIT:**

I used the awk answer below. All I had to do is remove the {next} statement and it works perfectly.

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Could you give some information on that?

Comment: Yes of course my apologies. I am trying to go through a file that lists when scripts are run. So i only care if a script is finished.. if it is finished I will increment the counter. However, the scripts are run in blocks.. morning afternoon and night. So I am breaking the loop with "blah blah" (Scripts Completed) because that will be the amount of scripts finished in the morning

Comment: You will have a much easier time both doing this and finding relevant resources if you don't try to do it all at once, and instead focus on making individual parts work. For example, you should define two strings `a="hello world" b="panda"` and try to write an if statement that compares them (and then setting `b=$a` to ensure that both positive and negative cases work). It's much easier to google "how do I compare strings in a shell script" than "how do I read through a text file line by line checking if that line has a certain string".

Comment: I guess my most important question is what does grep return if I set it to a variable.

Comment: Grep returns that, what it would return anyway. No matter if you point it to a variable or not.

Comment: Okay well I am still debugging my program and I guess having var1=$(grep -s "Completed" $line) it finds all of the matching lines first then will be checked in the loop.. Can you guys suggest another function besides grep?

Comment: Your invocation of `grep` results in `$line` being split into separate words on white-space characters, and each word is then interpreted as the name of a file, which `grep` then tries to open and search for your target string "Completed" in. The `-s` option masks this, because it causes `grep` not to complain about non-existent files, which would have been quite obvious otherwise... In order to search `$line`, you should use either `echo "${line}" | grep ...` or `grep ... <<<"${line}"`.

Comment: Oh I understand. But when I do var1=echo "${line}" | grep -s ..... does var1 get assigned the whole line if its true right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several errors.   Plus you may want to consider a tool that is meant to do this kind of thing.  awk is one of those tools.

```
awk '/blah blah/ {exit} 
     /Finished/ {count+=1} 
     {next}
     END{ print count} ' filename
```

The first line quits when it matches "blah blah" anywhere on the line.

The second line counts the number of "Finished" matches.

The {next} bit is there to keep reading and not print every line - this happens in some versions of awk.

The last line , END {} function, runs when the code completes the file.  It displays the value of count.

I chose the awk approach rather than trying to fix logic and syntax errors in the shell script.  If you need that kind of help consider playing almost every block (or line) of code all by itself on the command line.   I am assuming you used bash.

Errors examples

```
-eq to compare strings, use =, example:  [ "$var" = "something" ]
$(var1) should be either "${var1}" or "$var1" lines 4 and 8
```

grep returns a whole line, are you testing "blah blah" and expecting just and only just "blah blah" as the entire result?

Comment: I am going to try this right now.. Thank you for your answer I will let you know what happens. Im testing the grep blah blah $line against $line.. But your way seems a lot better. I heard awk can easily replace grep.

Comment: `awk '/Completed/ {exit} 
     /Finished/ {count+=1} 
     {next}
     END{ print count} ' filename` seems like its in a infinite loop

Comment: now I am trying to add more conditonals into the awk command. I have `awk ' / Completed/ { counter +=1}  Finished/ { if (counter = 1) mornCount +=1 if (counter =2) afterCount+=1 and if(counter=3) nightCounter+=1}  END{ print morn, after, and night counters}`

Answer (score 2):

Error #1:

> When I do var1=$(grep -s "Completed" $line) why does it find all
>   instances of Completed

In the above command `grep` expects `$line` to be a filename not a string. If you want to pass string you need to use pipe:

```
var1=$(echo "$line" | grep -s "Completed")
```

Or in Bash you can use string redirection:

```
var1=$(grep -s "Completed" <<<"$line")
```

Error #2:

There should be space between `if` and `[` (`[` is `test` command)

---

**This `grep` command will probably do the same as you are trying to do with that code:**

```
grep -v "Completed" file.txt | grep -c "Script Finished"
```

`grep -v "Completed" file.txt` returns the lines not containing "Completed" and sends to the next `grep` through the pipe which returns the line count which contain the text "Script Finished".

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. And clever way of using the grep.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this after the (current) accepted solution because the accepted solution is in a language that is not covered by the tags.

You can do the same thing in shell using a case statement.
(though for large files, awk or grep may be faster)

```
while read line; do
case "$line" in 
   *"Completed"*)break;;
   *"Script Finished"*)count=$((count + 1));;
esac
done < file.txt
```

note: this form of `while read line;` ... will omit the last line, if that is not ok, use `while read line || [ "$line" ]` (This is 1 reason why some IDEs will add an empty new line to the end of files)

Comment: Oh I didnt catch that! Thanks